# NullPointerException when trying to connect to WFS

Tags: geotools

I am new to WFS and geotools. I'm trying to connect to the LRIS WFS.

Code is below:

```
String getCapabilities = "https://lris.scinfo.org.nz/services;key=ENTER-KEY/wfs/layer-66?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities";

Map connectionParameters = new HashMap();
connectionParameters.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:GET_CAPABILITIES_URL", getCapabilities );

// Step 2 - connection      
DataStore data = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore( connectionParameters );

// Step 3 - discouvery
String typeNames[] = data.getTypeNames();
```

I get a null pointer exception on line:

```
String typeNames[] = data.getTypeNames();
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to check that the `DataStore` was opened (i.e. is not Null) before using it.

That said with the following code I get data back easily, I assume you have added your own key to the URL:

```
String getCapabilities = "https://lris.scinfo.org.nz/services;key=myKEY/wfs/layer-66?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities";

    Map connectionParameters = new HashMap();
    connectionParameters.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:GET_CAPABILITIES_URL", getCapabilities);
    connectionParameters.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:WFSDataStoreFactory:TIMEOUT", 10000000);
    // Step 2 - connection
    DataStore data = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(connectionParameters);
    if(data==null) {
      System.err.println("failed to open datastore at "+getCapabilities);
    }
    // Step 3 - discouvery
    String types[] = data.getTypeNames();
    for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(types[i]);

      String name = types[i];
      Query query = new Query(name);
      query.setCoordinateSystem(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
      SimpleFeatureSource source = data.getFeatureSource(name);
      SimpleFeatureType schema = source.getSchema();
      System.out.println(schema);
      SimpleFeatureCollection fc = source.getFeatures(query);
      int count = 0;
      while (fc.features().hasNext() && (count++ < 10)) {
        SimpleFeature sf = fc.features().next();
        System.out.println(sf);
      }
    }
  }
```

Note that I did have to turn up the timeout parameter as New Zealand is a long way away from me in the UK.